# Package updates display only in Package Manager

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

In "NuGet package Manager" the updates packages available are displayed.

On command line `Get-Package -Updates`, nothing is displayed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the dialog, you have 3 package sources configured, I suppose those updates come from the other two package sources than the official NuGet package source.

On the other than, in the console, you select only the official NuGet package source (in the combo box). That's why it doesn't show updates.